# v-menu content not appearing in ssr (nuxt 2 & vuetify)

Tags: nuxt.js, vuetify.js, server-side-rendering

I'm using vuetify with nuxt (with ssr). Without SSR it actually works pretty fine. Let's look a little bit in the example.

```html
<template>
  <div class="text-center">
    <v-menu offset-y>
      <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
        <v-btn
          color="primary"
          dark
          v-bind="attrs"
          v-on="on"
        >
          Dropdown
        </v-btn>
      </template>
      <v-list>
        <v-list-item
          v-for="(item, index) in items"
          :key="index"
        >
          <v-list-item-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-item-title>
        </v-list-item>
      </v-list>
    </v-menu>
  </div>
</template>
```

When running it normally, I see all the contents as it should. However when I run it without javascript it's not the case (I deactivated with `Ctrl+Shift+P` -> `disable javascript` in chrome to test). The button does not appear, it appears only once the javascript has been loaded. Thus, having an impact in the Cumulative Layout Shift (CLS).

I actually found a workaround while playing with the html elements.
Instead of

```html
<v-menu offset-y>
```

I write

```html
<v-menu offset-y style="display:block;">
```

I know that the component does not work like that (just displaying or not). However it did the trick for ssr. I just would like to know why that happens and if there is a proper way to do it (in my opinion, it should work out of the box, but well...)

A bit of information about the packages:

```
"nuxt": "^2.17.2",
"vuetify": "^2.6.1"
```